# Why does my Thread.Sleep causes the app to crash?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I'm making a C++ Winforms Application that consumes a C# Library. I found that my application crashes exactly at the point where my code reaches Thread.Sleep in my C# library. Here is the code in the C# library:

```
IAsyncResult result = SomeProcessHereEvent?.BeginInvoke(xmlForEQ, null, null);

//System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250); //putting thread.sleep here will cause the app to crash here, confirming the cause

DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;
while (!result.IsCompleted)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200); //this causes the app to crash
}

string xmlReply = string.Empty;
if (result.IsCompleted)
{
    xmlReply = SomeProcessHereEvent.EndInvoke(result);
}
```

When the app crashes, the error message that I got is in my C++ app, here : [image]

How do I proceed to get closer to solving this problem?

Comment: Please post source code and exception details as text, not images.

Answer (score -1):

If you are calling Thread.sleep() on MainThread i.e UI thread, It will freeze the UI and causes the thread to definitely stop executing for a given amount of time; So if there is no other thread needs to be run, CPU will goes in Idle mode.

**Why is thread.sleep() not recommended?**
One of the way to achieve synchronization, implement wait is by calling Thread. sleep() function however, it is not recommended because this is not very stable and unreliable. The time has to be specified in milliseconds.